# Unable to click/exclude/pass ok on javascript alert appears in webpage using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to click the download button of website from excel, in the `onclick` event a javascript has been called and that will retrieve data from the page and convert that to csv format and get downloaded as excel file. Here I can able to click the button however it triggers a popup and macro execution freeze until we click on  ”ok” in the webpage , I cannot use `send keys` and `window locate method` since macro gets freeze in the onclick action. I tried many approaches but nothing works, I can’t individually replace the `onclick` function with `“”` because that alert popup coded at the first line of function where download code is executed so I can’t override it.

Code Behind button:

```html
<input id="Download" onclick="loadDataForDownload();" type="button" value="Download Data Report">
```

Java script(only few line since its huge one)

```
 Function loadDataForDownload(){
  alert("This transaction may take few minutes");
  var total ="0.00";
```

Approaches tried:

```
With HTMLdoc.parentWindow
  .execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};", "JScript"
  .execScript "loadDataForDownload();", "JScript"
End With
```

using send keys

```
Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
```

here `sendkeys` funtion not at all executed because macro execution paused when popup appears in webpage

Screenshot of popup:

[image]

Please help me on how to Exclude/ click on the javascript alert popup in ie.

Comment: Can you edit your question and place a picture of the popup message window? I have in mind to use API (FindWindow, FindWindowEx, SendMessage) to find the window, button and click it using SendMessage. You can open **another Excel session, or something else using VBA, Corel Draw, Word etc.**), where a form having a timer will search for such a window and close it. I think you can automate the new session creation, opening the workbook keeping the form, showing it and close workbook, quit session.. If you have Spy++ you can check the  window handler and which is the child relation of the button.

Comment: @FaneDuru added the popup window pic.

Comment: Sorry @FaneDuru it required credentials to navigate and had some sensitive information in it, please guide me on how to proceed further.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, so if my understanding is correct I am supposed to use multithreading and call the function in another workbook which has code to find the window and click on ok also b4 starting that code there should be some wait time implemented so in the source code if i clicked that button the popup will appear meanwhile my another code will find the window and click on ok. Is my understanding is correct please share your thoughts.

Comment: You're overriding `window.confirm` but the js uses `alert` which is not the same thing.

Comment: `.execScript "window.alert = function(){return true;};", "JScript"`

Comment: Excellent @TimWilliams it works absolutely fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `window.confirm` but the js uses `alert` which is not the same thing:

```vb
With HTMLdoc.parentWindow
   .execScript "window.alert = function(){return true;};", "JScript"
  .execScript "loadDataForDownload();", "JScript"
End With
```