# How to close a web message from IE VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

I,ve been dealing with a issue during my web scraping.
My problem is that when I click to "Submit" a form, it pops-up a web message that I've not been able to close.

I´ve already try the sendKeys Method but no success.
here is the link of the web page:
https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/corrigirPorIndice.do?method=corrigirPorIndice
Here is a print of the info to put in the webpage
[Here is a print of the info to put in the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlEak.png)
The message appers when you click the button on the left "Corrigir Valor"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsBq1.png)
the messege

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDeBu.png)

obs. pressing enter or esc with the keyboard close it, but I`m not been able to do it in the code

here is the code if may be helpful

```
Sub atualizacao_valores()
Dim data_base As String
Dim data_atualizacao As String
Dim valor_face As String
Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
Dim html As HTMLDocument



Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.navigate "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/exibirFormCorrecaoValores.do?method=exibirFormCorrecaoValores&aba=1"
ie.Visible = True
Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop

data_base_ipcae = "01/2022"
data_atualizacao_ipcae = "12/2022"
valor_face = "100000"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
Set html = ie.document
Set drp = html.getElementById("selIndice")

drp.selectedIndex = 4

ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(1).Value = data_base_ipcae
ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(2).Value = data_atualizacao_ipcae
ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(3).Value = valor_face


ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("botao")(0).Click
`here happens the pop up that I cant close


...
end sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089578/unable-to-click-exclude-pass-ok-on-javascript-alert-appears-in-webpage-using-exc/65096241#65096241

Comment: Why don't you try using xmlhttp requests instead? All you need to do is issue a post HTTP requests with appropriate parameters to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion given by Tim Williams.

Adding code below just above the line when you click the button could suppress the Alert().

```
With html.parentWindow
   .execScript "window.alert = function(){return true;};", "JScript"
End With
```

**Your modified code:**

```
Sub atualizacao_valores()
    Dim data_base As String
    Dim data_atualizacao As String
    Dim valor_face As String
    Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.navigate "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/CALCIDADAO/publico/exibirFormCorrecaoValores.do?method=exibirFormCorrecaoValores&aba=1"
    ie.Visible = True
    Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    data_base_ipcae = "01/2022"
    data_atualizacao_ipcae = "12/2022"
    valor_face = "100000"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Set html = ie.document
    Set drp = html.getElementById("selIndice")
    
    drp.selectedIndex = 4
    
    ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(1).Value = data_base_ipcae
    ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(2).Value = data_atualizacao_ipcae
    ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(3).Value = valor_face
    
    With html.parentWindow
        .execScript "window.alert = function(){return true;};", "JScript"
        
    End With
    
    ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("botao")(0).Click
    
    
End Sub
```

I have tested this code on my end and it is suppressing the Alert message.

You could test it and let us know your test results.